# I want to create a new row in mongoDB only if current options return no matches

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I want to run this line of code

```
`await shortModel.create({ long, short });`
```

Only if there are no entries in my database with the exact same parameters.

Essentially I want to run (in pseudocode)
`

```
if(!exists_in_shortModel({long, short})) {
    await shortModel.create({ long, short });
} else {
   // do nothing
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out

```
let shortURLtoLookUp = await shortModel.findOne({ long, short });

if (!shortURLtoLookUp) {
    await shortModel.create({ long, short });
    console.log(long, short)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, check if the value it's valid or not with findOne || find in MongoDB

```
cosnt validData = await shortModel.findOne({long, short});
if (validData !== null || validData.row !== 0){
   // do nothing
} else {
    await shortModel.create({ long, short });
}
```